# input different ways of date to powershell

Tags: powershell

I am writing a script to get the results based on the user input, here user can give in date or date time... i need to get the results based on the input (date or datetime).

I have tried like below:

```
$StartDate  = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the start date of the logs, Ex: 17/07/2017 or 17/07/2017 09:00:00'

$culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture

$pattern = 'dd\/MM\/yyyy HH:mm:ss', 'dd\/MM\/yyyy'

$params['After'] = [DateTime]::ParseExact($StartDate, $pattern, $culture)
```

getting the below error:

```
Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
+     $params['After'] = [DateTime]::ParseExact <<<< ($StartDate, $pattern, $culture)
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Please suggest, am i missing anything here.

Answer (score 5):

I've had good luck using PowerShell's default Get-Date function on dates.  I would try just using the following:

```
$StartDate = Get-Date (Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the start date of the logs, Ex: 17/07/2017 or 17/07/2017 09:00:00')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you still would like to use `ParseExact()`, your issue was that `$pattern` was an array of strings rather than a string. You could check which pattern to use and then only pass that pattern.

```
$StartDate  = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter the start date of the logs, Ex: 17/07/2017 or 17/07/2017 09:00:00'

$culture = [Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture

if ($startdate -match '^\w\w\/\w\w\/\w\w\w\w$') {
    $pattern = 'dd\/MM\/yyyy'
} else {
    $pattern = 'dd\/MM\/yyyy HH:mm:ss'
}

$params['After'] = [DateTime]::ParseExact($StartDate, $pattern, $culture)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably just use a short function; something like:

```
function Read-Date {
  param(
    [String] $prompt
  )
  $result = $null
  do {
    $s = Read-Host $prompt
    if ( $s ) {
      try {
        $result = Get-Date $s
        break
      }
      catch [Management.Automation.PSInvalidCastException] {
        Write-Host "Date not valid"
      }
    }
    else {
      break
    }
  }
  while ( $true )
  $result
}
```

Then you can write this:

```
Read-Date "Enter a date"
```

The code will prompt until the user enters a valid date-like string. Once the user enters a valid date string, the function's output is a `[DateTime]` object.